# Image not occupying full ImageView in layout

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-image

I have created a gallery which has default images when , one of it is clicked and displayed in other activity, but my problem is it does not occupy the whole screen when the image is loaded.

Here's the xml-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drag_activity_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DragActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewEdit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/i1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the images is loaded to this imageview from activity, using the following code.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        int ImageId = intent.getIntExtra("drawableId", 0);

        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewEdit);
        imgView.setImageResource(ImageId);
```

[image]

Is their a way where image occupies the whole image view.
Experts please help me, am new to android. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
imgView.setImageResource(ImageId);
```

to

```
imgView.setBackgroundResource(ImageId);
```

Answer (score 0):

set the `android:scaleType` attribute on the ImageView, something like centerCrop should fill the screen

Answer (score 0):

Change the [`ScaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) of the `ImageView`. Add this to your `ImageView` tag:

```
android:scaleType = "fitCenter"
```

Answer (score 0):

use imageView.setBackground() property

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Add `android:scaleType="FIT_XY"` to your ImageView.